# DRF: Redirect unauthenticated users to login form

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

Is there a way to redirect users who didn't pass through `rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated` permission to login page?

I can achieve it by rewriting *dispatch* method of my ApiView and adding extra
NotAuthenticated exception catcher, but is there a softer way to do this?

```
class IndexView(APIView):
        permission_classes = [
        IsAuthenticated,
    ]
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        ...

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs
        request = self.initialize_request(request, *args, **kwargs)
        self.request = request
        self.headers = self.default_response_headers  # deprecate?

        try:
            self.initial(request, *args, **kwargs)

            # Get the appropriate handler method
            if request.method.lower() in self.http_method_names:
                handler = getattr(self, request.method.lower(),
                                  self.http_method_not_allowed)
            else:
                handler = self.http_method_not_allowed

            response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

        except NotAuthenticated: "<----  added by me"
            return redirect("/login")
        
        except Exception as exc:
            response = self.handle_exception(exc)

        self.response = self.finalize_response(request, response, *args, **kwargs)
        return self.response
```

Comment: I think it is a good practice to not return a redirect page but instead an http status of 401 informing your frontend to do the redirect part itself. This way your API would be more scalable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it as follows by overriding the exception handler of rest framework:

create a new file in any app with the name `handler.py` and add as follows:

```
from rest_framework.exceptions import PermissionDenied
from rest_framework.views import exception_handler
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def redirect_to_log(exec, data):
    if isinstance(exec, PermissionDenied):
        return redirect('login')
    return exception_handler(exec, data)
```

Then, make this change in your `settings.py` file:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'EXCEPTION_HANDLER': 'app.handler.redirect_to_log'
}
```

Now, whenever the permission check fails, the user will be redirected to the login page.

**Note:** This applies to any of the exception where ever it fails. To have a more ingrain control, you can override the handle_exception in APIView or Viewsets

**EDIT:**

To do it per view/viewset basis you can user the following approach

In your `serializers.py` file create a custom `PermissionDenied` wrapper as follows:

from rest_framework.exceptions import PermissionDenied

```
class RedirectToLoginException(PermissionDenied):
    pass

class CheckUserPermission(BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        # your logic for checking if user is authenticated or not
        if not_allowed:
            raise RedirectToLoginException
```

Now, in your APIView you can do as follows:

```
from your_app.permissions import RedirectToLoginException, CheckUserPermission
class IndexView(APIView):

    permission_classes = [CheckUserPermission]

    def handle_exception(self, exc):
        if isinstance(exc, RedirectToLoginException):
            return redirect('login')
        else:
            super().handle_exception(exc)
```

By this method, only when permission checks for CheckUserPermission fails, you will be redirected to the login page.